# want to study the Satoshi (bitcoind) code

Tags: bitcoind

Is there any blog or document that gives a basic "tour" or "overview" of the Satoshi code?  I could just dive in but it would help to read an introduction first.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the Bitcoin protocol specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification) and in more general [the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page). Also, [the original paper of Satoshi](http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) is a good read.

EDIT: I recently found [an article on Bitcoin Talk about the Satoshi client code structure](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41718.0). It's an interesting read too!

Comment: I have done that already, but I would like something that tells me how the source files are organized, what the key classes are, etc.

Comment: @RentFree Read main.cpp and main.h and you'll have a good idea of that. The most important logic and classes are in those files.